# Migration of web application backend MS Access 2003 to MS Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, windows-server-2003, ms-access-2010, database-migration

I have an asp application residing on Windows server 2003 -32bit and backend for the application is MS Access 2000. When I upgrade it to MS Access 2010, it throws error: 'Unrecognized Database format'
I even tried to upgrade Access driver on server but of no luck. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the [ACE drivers installed](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255). You said you updated the Access driver on the server but I'm not sure you actually installed the drivers that are needed for the new .accdb format.

By default, Windows only contains drivers for Jet, that allow you to use `.mdb` Access databases without installing anything new.

On the other hand, the new 2007/2010 Access format `'.accdb` needs to have the drivers installed separately.

You also need to make sure that your connection string to the database is updated:

```
string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=16;Data Source=C:\...\mydb.accdb;user id=;password=;";
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to upgrading the database file itself from .mdb to .accdb you'll need to make two changes on the server:

1. You'll need to download and install the Access Database Engine, available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255).
2. You'll also need to update your connection details for your ASP application. For a DSN-less connection you'll have to update your connection string to one of the formats described [here](http://connectionstrings.com/access-2007). For example, an OLEDB connection string will have to be updated to `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;`.